# Can I use Friedburg's linear algebra as a *first* course?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, advice

I want to use this book as the next step in my math journey. Although I’m not done yet, by the time I plan on starting this book I would have already completed Stewart Calculus and proofs by Jay Cummings (an intro-to-proofs book). The reason I want to read Friedberg over other books is that it’s a proof-based book because I really don’t like computation-based book, as they feel too boring and repetitive. So if I already know calc 1 to 3, along with an intro-to-proofs book, am I ready to read linear algebra by Friedburg? If not, then what am I missing and what other books/subjects can I study instead?

Comment: Yes, you can use it (this was my first introduction to linear algebra), and you can also practice proof-writing from it. Also, side remark: linear algebra should ideally be learnt simultaneously with analysis/calculus (I learnt both simultaneously in my first year), so there’s no reason for you to wait :)